# Create Custom Form in PWA magento2 and save data into the DB

Tags: magento2, forms, pwa, pwa-studio

I need to create a custom Form into the PWA magento2. in ReactJs Also I want to save this data into the magento2 database.

I know for this I have used GraphQL Mutation query but I need some more help for this if anyone has an idea about that so please guide me.

Thanks.